# Where can I find the default behaviour on an event for a WPF control?

Tags: wpf, documentation, event-handling

I would like to know what a given control does on a given event by default.

e.g.: what does a TextBox do when I double-click on it?
I don't necessarily need the exact code, I could do with a basic description. Even just knowing that a given Event is managed by WPF by default would help me in some cases.

I have looked on msdn, in the classes definitions, in the controlTemplate examples, etc... without success.

is there a doc that contains this info, or any way to find it?

**edit:** the reason I need this is because I have a few controls that inherit system controls, and I must trap absolutely almost every user input on those controls and prevent WPF to take over and apply the default behaviour (selecting the current word when you double-click on a textBox for instance). So I need to trap every possible event and put Handled = true. But I would still like to be sure that I will not break anything or, if I break something, at least to be aware of it...

Comment: Sounds a little bit weird. Perhaps you should think of another approach to implement your controls at all. Why do you want suppress the standard behavior?

Comment: I'm updating on a legacy app that was previously designed in win32 and basically, every single event must be passed to the app so that it applies a custom behaviour. I'm really not ahhpy with this way of doing things either but... I'm not my own boss :)

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't see this working. Why did you decide to go with WPF? WinForms are much closer to the traditional WinApi architecture... Also, are you sure you can't write the GUI layer to be relatively independent on the legacy application and only use it when absolutely necessary?

Comment: ah yes, I quite agree with this, but as said above, I am not my own master. I did not chose WPF, and I did not chose the way the app was written. I have to add that this app is 20 years old. My company even developed its own language to program this app. Now I'm asked to update the layer that translate the apps command into windows controls and vice/versa. It was all done in Win32 and now they want WPF since it has a lot more possibilities regarding design. It works pretty well actually but is kind of a hassle to do. So I'm simply looking for ways to spare some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think it is safe to conclude that this info is not readily available.

my best shot is probably to use the bits of code available on codeplex and deduce what happens for each type of object from there...